# Staircase "#" program in Python, correct output but not qualifying default test cases

Tags: python, python-2.x

Write a program that prints a staircase of size .

**Input Format**: A single integer, n, denoting the size of the staircase.

**Output Format**: Print a staircase of size n using # symbols and spaces.

Note: The last line must have 0 spaces in it.

My program is giving correct output but not passing the default test cases in hackerrank. My code is as follows:

```
import sys
val = 1
def stair(n, val):
    for i in range(n):
        res1 = " " *n
        res2 = "#" *val
        print res1 + res2
        val = val+1
        n = n-1
n = int(raw_input().strip())
stair(n, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Note: The last line must have 0 spaces in it.

Your program is printing a space in the last line

```
import sys
val = 1

def stair(n, val):
    for i in range(n+1):
        res1 = "-" *(n-i)   # putting - instead of space to test
        res2 = "#" *val
        print(res1 + res2)
        val = val+1
        # n = n-1


# n = int(input().strip())
n= 5
stair(n, 1)
```

Note: This code is in python 3.x

Answer (score 1):

As @Anonta mentioned - you got space char in last line. But, instead of using `for` loop - I suggest use `while` loop, like this:

```
def stairs(n):
    n_spaces = n-1
    n_stairs = 1
    while n:
        print(" "*n_spaces + "#"*n_stairs)
        n -= 1
        n_spaces -= 1
        n_stairs += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.x

```
import sys

def staircase(n):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        print(" "*(n-i)+ "#"*i)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    n = 3

    staircase(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Subsequently, this works in python 2.x:

```
import sys
val = 1
def stair(n, val):
    for i in range(n+1):
        res1 = "_" *n
        res2 = "#" *val
        print res1 + res2
        val = val+1
        n = n-1
n = int(raw_input().strip())
stair(n, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def staircase(n):
   for i in range(n):
      output = ' '*(n-i-1)+'#'*(i+1)
      print(output)
if __name__ == '__main__':
   n = int(input())
   staircase(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

This gonna help

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(n-i):
        print(" ",end="")
    while i>0:
        print("#",end="")
        i -=1
    print("")
```